# Set the size of main window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to set predefined window size. Example application:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text="Example button")
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The resulting window is very small. It is as big as button. How to make the window large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use geometry.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text="Example button")
button.pack()

root.geometry("200x200")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`tkinter.Tk.geometry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tk-option-data-types) method:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")  # Set the window's size to 500 by 500 pixels

button = Button(root, text="Example button")
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```